# SSH tunnel, port forwarding setup

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I have a simple bash script for SSH tunneling

```
createTunnel() {
  /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/miner/EC2.pem -f -N -R 10022:localhost:22 -L 19922:ubuntu@server.com:22 ubuntu@server.com
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo Tunnel created successfully
  else
    echo An error occurred
  fi
}
/usr/bin/ssh -p 19922 localhost ls > /dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo Creating new tunnel
  createTunnel
fi
```

When I run it, I get the following errors, what are the possible causes?

```
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 10022
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 19922
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

Comment: many...  try running ssh in verbose mode.

Comment: I guess you've run your script twice but only one process can listen to a specific port. `netstat -ntpl | grep "19922\|10022" `